# RTK Query UseLazyQuery trigger: how to get the correct type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rtk-query

I need to get correct typing for trigger, that I'm passing to the child component, cannot find how to type it.

```
...      
const [trigger] = useLazyGetQuery();
...
<ChildComponent trigger={trigger} />
...
```

Child component where I need to type somehow RTK query trigger except *any*:

```
export const ChildComponent = ({ trigger }: { trigger: any }) => {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found correct type:

```
import { LazyQueryTrigger } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react/buildHooks";
import {
  BaseQueryFn,
  FetchArgs,
  FetchBaseQueryError,
  FetchBaseQueryMeta,
  QueryDefinition,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import { IDemoRequest } from "../../../../../../../modules/Demo/apis/interfaces/IDemoRequest";

export type LazyGetTriggerType = LazyQueryTrigger<
  QueryDefinition<
    IDemoRequest,            // Request parameters type
    BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, object, FetchBaseQueryMeta>,
    never,
    number[],                // Response type
    "api"                    // Your reducerPath
  >
>;
```

Change any to LazyGetTriggerType

```
export const ChildComponent = ({ trigger }: { trigger: LazyGetTriggerType }) => {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extending from OP's answer, to use this generically you can define request param type and response type as generic types `<T, U>`, so that it can be shared within your project:

```
export type LazyGetTriggerType<T, U> = LazyQueryTrigger<
  QueryDefinition<
    T,                // Request parameters type
    BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, object, FetchBaseQueryMeta>,
    never,
    U,                // Response type
    "api"             // Your reducerPath
  >
>;
```